# Is it possible to configure Wireless Settings via text file in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, kiosk

I am sending out kiosks with no control panel access and no keyboard.  Problem is, somehow the wireless card needs to be configured to work with routers.  So need to specify SSID and encryption settings without actually keying it in on the kiosk.  Hoping to be able to put in a  USB drive with a wirelessconfig.txt file and have windows XP pick it up and modify the settings.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: There is no built in way to do that. Can you deploy your own software on the kiosks? Then you might be able to create a windows service that checks for newly inserted disks and read config from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup this sort of thing with the win32 api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705945%28v=VS.85%29.aspx - as for some app that does this already maybe that is a question for the superuser forums

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Seems a bit complex, I'll try the superuser forums too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write a small script to pick up the settings from the USB and use the windows API to configure the network.
Windows 7 has the WPS capability built-in.You might want to check that out.
Windows XP SP3 is supposed to have WPS but I'm not sure about it either.